# Angular service to transfer data between components (standalone components - NG14)

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular-services, angular-standalone-components

I know we can use a service, @Input and @Output so move data between components.

For example I can have this in a service:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    myMethod$: Observable<any>;
    private myMethodSubject = new Subject<any>();

    constructor() {
        this.myMethod$ = this.myMethodSubject.asObservable();
    }

    myMethod(data) {
        this.myMethodSubject.next(data);
    }
}
```

I am now building standalone components and need to (for example):

```
ComponentA -> lazy loads -> ModalComponent and now wants to send some data to it parameters or an object with data.
```

My question is...

For standalone / lazy loaded components in Angular 14, is this still a good way to do this of is there a better way?

Comment: I understood your question, but, where are you stuck ? Can you provide some lines of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standalone components are a new feature released in `14.0.0` version of Angular. Is supposed to make our work easier but the logics are still the same and the achievement methods are equal to the past. nothing is changed.